# Can several project have the same namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a website with a lot of classes and I'd like to reuse some in another project.

In order to avoid a huge ddl with lot of unused classes in my new project, could I split my websites classes in several "sub-projects" while keeping the same namespace?

This could results in having this kind of line

```
namespace MyWebSiteNameSpace
{
```

in several distincts project. Will this lead to errors?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably make more sense to extract the common classes to a separate project and namespace and reference this project from the web site projects.

A good reference for separating the VS solution into distinct projects with separation of concern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) check Onion Architecture:

http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/

among a many other resources.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible and will not lead to an error.

Comment: it will not lead to an error in all cases. but when recombining code from different projects it might lead to problems later.

Comment: @mnagel What problems later? The OP might want to know.